# Fatch array from a js file into php and then encode into a json

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a js file which contains some data in the array form.
http://localhost/js/data.js
 The information is something like

```
var subjectCodeArray=["CS/ Computer Science","AF/ Art Facalty",...];
```

and I want to get the information from the array "subjectCodeArray" into my php file "subjectCode.php" and then want to encode it into json array.
I don't know how to do it pleas help me to do it.

thanks in advance.....

Comment: link is not usefull . its localhost address

Comment: You'll want to use AJAX. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer first of all fatch the data from js file
    $data = file_get_contents("./data.js");

```
Create a substring which contain the data from starting "[" to the ending "]"
$substrdata = substr($data, strpos($data,'[')+1, strpos($data,']') - strpos($data,'['));

then replase "\" with space
$substrdata = str_replace("\"", "", $substrdata);

then replace the singal cotes
$substrdata = str_replace("'", "", $substrdata);

and the explode it in the bases of comma and store it in array 
$arr=explode(",",$substrdata);
$json_response = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{
    $row_array['student'] = preg_replace("/\//",'',$arr[$i]);
    array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}
```

and finally encode in json form
    $output = json_encode(array('student_info'=>$json_response));
    echo $output;